# How can I check if an index is defined?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a loop that is getting data from a form:

```
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $id = $dataEntity->getId();
    $content = $data['form['.$id.']'];
    $dataEntity->setContent($content);
}
```

I have one problem. In the case that `form['.$id.']` is valid than the code is working. But when it is not valid I get the error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: form[5207c07b25]

So I tried to change the code like this

```
 foreach ($data as $d) {
     $id = $dataEntity->getId();
     $formData = "form['.$id.']";
     if(isset($formData)){
         $content = $formData;
     } else {
          $content = "";
     }
     $dataEntity->setContent($content);
 }
```

But still I get the same error message.

Comment: $formData = isset($data['form[' . $id . ']') ? $data['form[' . $id . ']' : '';

Comment: `isset` or `empty` or `(condition)?true : false` ternary or  `$foo??$a??$b;` null coalescing

Comment: Why don't you check whether the combined index `$formData` exists in your `$data` array? The given code only checks whether the variable that you've defined a line earlier exists, which is, well, always true ;)

Comment: If you're running PHP7, `$formData =  $data["form[$id]"] ?? '';`

Comment: @Qirel This is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the index exists in the array. The index string itself will always be set:

```
 foreach ($data as $d) {
     $id = $dataEntity->getId();
     $formData = "form[".$id."]";
     if(isset($data[$formData])){
         $content = $data[$formData];
     } else {
          $content = "";
     }
     $dataEntity->setContent($content);
 }
```

Comment: just for kicks - for one action, I'd say it's better to go ternary: `$content = (isset($data[$formData]) ? $data[$formData] : '');`

Comment: @treyBake If you use PHP 7 you should use `$content = $data[$formData] ?? ''`

Comment: Noice! Didn't know about this .. ! :D